# Find string in subfolders and move to new location

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm currently trying to find a string in multiple files.... for example 'Apple' once found i would like to move the files which contain 'Apple' to a new folder.

This is my current script:

```
findstr /s /m /l /c:"Apple" "C:\Users\User\Desktop\created\*.php"
```

This finds all of the .php pages which includes the word 'Apple', however it currently lists them, i can't seem to move them into a new location.

I understand i will need to delete "/m" as this prints the file names...

So how do i move them into a new folder?

Thank you

Comment: This is more of a Superuser question. Look here: https://superuser.com/questions/1007352/using-a-batch-script-to-move-specific-files-with-specific-file-contents

Comment: don't delete `/m`, because you *need*  the filenames for the `move` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put a `for` loop around:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /smlc:"Apple" "C:\Users\User\Desktop\created\*.php"') do ECHO move "%%~fa" "Z:\New Location\"
```

Note: this is batch file syntax. For use directly on command line, replace every `%%` with a single `%`.

This just echoes the `move` commands. After troubleshooting, remove the `ECHO` to arm the `move` command.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different alternative, *(creates as required a new directory named as the search word, to move it into, and only moves if the file does not already exist in there)*:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "strPath=%UserProfile%\Desktop\created"
Set "strExtn=.php"
Set "strWord=Apple"
Set "strDest=%UserProfile%\Desktop\test"

CD /D "%strPath%" 2>Nul || Exit /B
For /F "Delims=" %%A In (
    'Findstr /MISC:"%strWord%" "%strPath%\*%strExtn%" 2^>Nul'
) Do RoboCopy "%%~dpA." "%strDest%\%strWord%" "%%~nxA" /MOV>Nul
```

*Just modify the values of the variables, lines `2`-`5`, as necessary*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this suggestion works great

Comment: @GRAY, I added it simply because your question was non-specific with regards the 'new folder', so I'm satisfied if you found something in it of use.