# Find specific string in subfolders and move to new location

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am referencing the solution posted by Compo on this topic:
[BATCH Find string in subfolders and move to new location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51846870/batch-find-string-in-subfolders-and-move-to-new-location)

In which I used his script to retrieve only the files containing "TP" and transferring to the target folder. This works for some PCs (works on either Windows 7 or Win 10 PCs) but most other PCs (with similar OS) STILL PULL files with containing variants "TF" or "TA" in the strWord.

```
@Echo Off
Set "strPath=C:\temp\source\"
Set "strExtn=.tar"
Set "strWord=TP"
Set "strDest=C:\temp\target\"

CD /D "%strPath%" 2>Nul || Exit /B
echo %strPath%
For /F "Delims=" %%A In (
    'Findstr /MISC:"%strWord%" "%strPath%\*%strExtn%" 2^>Nul'
) Do RoboCopy "%%~dpA." "%strDest%\%strWord%" "%%~nxA" /MOV>Nul
```

I have tried making similar batch files run through task scheduler to pull and sort out the files that contain strWord "TA" and "TF" as well, however on those PCs that do not work, I see that the 'Findstr' filter does not work.

May I know if there is a way to improve the findstring to read the whole strword like and explicitly look for "TP" key word and not accept the "TA" or "TF" as well?

Comment: Since the files you are examining are `.tar` files, which contain compressed data, it's quite possible that those files also contain the string `tp` (in any case, as you're invoking `/i`). How do ***you*** define "contain TP"? "Does not work" means "does not do what I expect". Without knowing what you expect and what the results are, explicitly, we're guessing. Need  some more clarifiation here.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Magoo. The .tar files I am sorting can be opened in a text editor and these contain 1 string EITHER TP, TA & TF.-->these are the strWords i use to differentiate the files that I need and don't need. In this case if the file contains 'TP' this is the file i need copied and moved. The .tar files that contain 'TA' or 'TF' do not need to be moved. Let me know if you require more information.

Comment: Well, it would appear that you and `findstr` have different opinions about whether some of the "non-tp-containing" files contain `"tp"` or not. Without access to those files, we have to rely on your analysis. Try, from the prompt, `findstr /i /c:"tp" "name of a non-tp-containing file"` and if there is any report from `findstr`, try using an editor to find the string in that file, `findstr` having reported its presence within-context.

Comment: @compo sorry, total noob. other than trying to bump up your solution(earlier it the system did not allow me but it mentioned it registered by response to your previous solution)--how do we get you rewarded properly?

Comment: @magoo the sample .tar file would look like this(with Line 12 containing the strWord TP, TA or TF: 'code'Line1 Line2
Line3
Line4
Line5 
Line6
Line7 
Line8
Line9
Line10
Line11
TP
Line13
Line14
Line15
Line16 
Line17

Comment: @entity_13: you can accept one answer (that you feel helped you most or added the most value for you) and upvote (any number of) other answers that you feel were helpful.